# Memory mapping and variable location of shared library compiled with -fPIC

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, elf, position-independent-code

I am using a Linux box and I want to figure out the addresses of symbols inside a Position-Independent-Code shared library during runtime, now I can achieve that according to some observation, however, I still have some questions about the program/library loading (yeah, I know how but I don't know why). Assume we have the following two C source files:

```
// file: main.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern int global_field;
void main() {
    printf("global field(%p) = %d\n", &global_field, global_field);
}

// file: lib.c
int global_field = 1;
```

And we compile the above code with follow command:

```
gcc -fPIC -g -c lib.c -o lib.o      # note the -fPIC flag here
gcc -fPIC -g -c main.c -o main.o    # note the -fPIC flag here
gcc -shared -o lib.so lib.o
gcc -o main main.o ./lib.so
```

And `readelf -sW lib.so` shows the `global_field` symbol:

```
Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
  ...
  8: 0000000000201028     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   21 global_field
  ...
```

And `readelf -lW lib.so` outputs the following program headers:

```
...
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x00065c 0x00065c R E 0x200000
  LOAD           0x000df8 0x0000000000200df8 0x0000000000200df8 0x000234 0x000238 RW  0x200000
  DYNAMIC        0x000e18 0x0000000000200e18 0x0000000000200e18 0x0001c0 0x0001c0 RW  0x8
  NOTE           0x000190 0x0000000000000190 0x0000000000000190 0x000024 0x000024 R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x000df8 0x0000000000200df8 0x0000000000200df8 0x000208 0x000208 R   0x1
```

And now we run the program, it outputs the following:

```
global field(0x7ffff7dda028) = 1
```

And `cat /proc/<pid>/maps` outputs the following:

```
...
7ffff7bd9000-7ffff7bda000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 18650951    /.../lib.so
7ffff7bda000-7ffff7dd9000 ---p 00001000 fd:02 18650951    /.../lib.so
7ffff7dd9000-7ffff7dda000 r--p 00000000 fd:02 18650951    /.../lib.so
7ffff7dda000-7ffff7ddb000 rw-p 00001000 fd:02 18650951    /.../lib.so
...
```

Sorry it's a little too much code here... Now my questions are:

1. As you see, there are **TWO** `LOAD` segments in program headers, but there are **FOUR** memory mappings, why there are two more mappings?
2. For the two `LOAD` segments, how to figure out which segment maps to which memory region? Is there any standard or any manual?
3. the symbol `global_field`'s value is `0000000000201028` (see the output of `readelf -sW lib.so`), however, according to the ELF standard:

> **In executable and shared object files, `st_value` holds a virtual address**. To make these files' symbols more useful for the runtime
>   linker, the section offset (file interpretation) gives way to a
>   virtual address (memory interpretation) for which the section number
>   is irrelevant.

I know this is Position-Independent-Code, it CANNOT be virtual address and MUST be some kind of offset. Subtract `global_field`'s address with the symbol's value: `0x7ffff7dda028 - 0x201028 = 0x7ffff7bd9000`, it seems that the offset is based on the beginning address of the lowest memory mapping (see the output of `cat /proc/<pid>/maps`). However, is there any standard telling us that, how to detect the symbols' value type (virtual address or offset) programmatically? And if it's an offset, why should the offset base on that and why doesn't it base on its own memory region (I guess its own region is the last one, as it has the write permission)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As you see, there are TWO LOAD segments in program headers, but there are FOUR memory mappings, why there are two more mappings?

Because `GNU_RELRO` tells the dynamic loader to make the first `0x208` bytes of the second `PT_LOAD` segment read-only.

If you link the library with `gcc -shared -o lib.so lib.o -Wl,-z,norelro`, you will only get 3 mappings ... Which still leaves the question of why are there 3 instead of two?

You'll note that this mapping:

```
7ffff7bda000-7ffff7dd9000 ---p 00001000 fd:02 18650951    /.../lib.so
```

is actually a "hole" in the process space (no access is allowed).
You'll also note that the alignment for second `PT_LOAD` (for both, actually) is very large: `0x200000`.

This is done to accomodate the possibility of running with 1MB pages.

If you re-link again, with `gcc -shared -o lib.so lib.o -Wl,-z,norelro,-z,max-page-size=4096`, you will now only have the two mappings you are expecting.

What actually happens for the default case is that the loader *must* preserve the offset between the first and the second `PT_LOAD` (or else the binary will not work correctly). So it creates a large mapping (covering both `PT_LOAD` segments) at kernel-selected address (via `mmap(0, ...)`). Then `mprotect`s the region from end of the first `PT_LOAD`, until the end of the entire mapping with no-access. And finally it `mmap`s the second `PT_LOAD` segment at desired address using `MAP_FIXED` flag, leaving a hole between the two mappings.

> For the two LOAD segments, how to figure out which segment maps to which memory region? Is there any standard or any manual?

You can tell pretty easily from offset. The mappings which have offset `0` correspond to the first `PT_LOAD`, the hole doesn't correspond to anything, and the mapping with offset `00001000` corresponds to the second `PT_LOAD`.

> it seems that the offset is based on the beginning address of the lowest memory mapping

Correct: it's the relocation for the entire `lib.so` ELF image (determined by the very first `mmap(0, ...)`. That relocation is applied to every symbol in the image.

> However, is there any standard telling us that, how to detect the symbols' value type (virtual address or offset) programmatically?

There is no standard. But you can use [dladdr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) to find out the "base address" (relocation). In particular, `dli_fbase; /* Base address at which shared object is loaded */`.